# How to initialize array in a derived class constructor, with variable name?

Tags: java, constructor, interface, derived

So here is a class:

```
public class Palya {
    Mezo[][] m;

    public Palya(Mezo[][] m){
        this.m = m;
}
```

And it's derived:

```
public class PalyaTeszt extends Palya{

    public PalyaTeszt(Mezo[][] m) {
        super(new Mezo[][]  {
                {new Szikla(),    new Szikla(),     new Viz(),        new Szikla(),     new Szikla(),     new Preri(true)},
                {new Szikla(),    new Szikla(),     new Preri(false), new Preri(false), new Preri(false), new Szikla()},
                {new Szikla(),    new Szikla(),     new Preri(false), new Preri(false), new Szikla(),     new Szikla()},
                {new Szikla(),    new Szikla(),     new Preri(false), new Szikla(),     new Viz(),        new Preri(false)},
                {new Szikla(),    new Szikla(),     new Preri(false), new Szikla(),     new Viz(),        new Szikla()},
                {new Preri(true), new Preri(false), new Preri(false), new Preri(false), new Preri(false), new Preri(false)}
        });
    }
}
```

In the derived constructor the array is initialized with an other class called Mezo, this Mezo[][] m class has methods that i would like to access to, but there is no name for it, like m.getSomething(). 
How can this be initialized in the way that i can  use the Mezo's methods?
Would it be better if the Palya was just an interface? 
The meaning of Palya is a 6x6 fields like chess board just for different purpose. 
I would like to have 6 different Palya.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read about the different access level that Java provides. They are `public`, `private`, default (no-specifier), and `protected`. You should also learn about Object Oriented principles such as data hiding. For example, you can create methods in the `Palya` class which in turn call methods on the `Mezo` objects in the array.

Comment: Your code is actually making a **Two-Dimensional Arrays**. You can access to method by getting separate items. For example: m[0][0] which will return the first class in the first array. Here a Szikla class.

Comment: If `PalyaTeszt` and `Palya` are in the same package, you can do `m.doSomething()` just fine.

Comment: Caution: Your `public PalyaTeszt(Mezo[][] m)` constructor never uses its `m` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you didn't put access level modifier for your `m` field in class `Palya`, it should look like this:

```
public class Palya {
    protected Mezo[][] m; // Note protected keyword

    public Palya(Mezo[][] m){
        this.m = m;
}
```

If no modifier is proveded there is default which allows access only inside that class and members of same package.

More about access modifiers in Java - [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Note that there is a "default" access level when none is provided. In this case, `protected` is probably the desired access level.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for suggestion